# timing a function / tasks in lua

Tags: timer, lua

I'm trying to determine how long certain statements take to run in my lua code. 
My code looks like this:

```
function test(self)
    local timer1
    local timer2
    local timer3
    timer1 = os.time()
    print('timer1 start time is:'.. timer1)
    --do some stuff. 
    print( 'Timer1 end time is:' , os.difftime(os.time(), timer1) )
    timer2 = os.time()
    print('timer2 start time is:'.. timer2)

    -- do a lot of stuff
    print( 'Timer2 end time is:' , os.difftime(os.time(), timer2) )

    timer3=os.time()
    print('timer3 start time is:'.. timer3)

    -- a lot of processing... 

    print( 'Timer3 end time is:' , os.difftime(os.time(), timer3) )
end
```

This is what the output looks like:

```
timer1 start time is:1401798084
Timer1 end time is: = 0
timer2 start time is:1401798084
Timer2 end time is: = 0
timer3 start time is:1401798084
Timer3 end time is: = 2
```

**Other things I've tried:**

[Lua - Current time in milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463101/lua-current-time-in-milliseconds)

In the above post, I found this snippet of code:

```
local x = os.clock()
local s = 0
for i=1,100000 do s = s + i end
os.execute("sleep "..1)
print(string.format("elapsed time: %.2f\n", os.clock() - x))
```

I added the sleep time... but when it runs, I get the output:

```
elapsed time: 0.00
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong. If you have suggestions on how I can fix / improve this, I'm all ears.  In the interim, I'm going to revisit the lua site to read up on os.difftime() in case I'm using it incorrectly.

**EDIT 1**

I changed the test code to look like this:

```
local x = os.clock()
local s = 0
for i=1,100000 do 
    s = s + i 
    os.execute("sleep "..1)
end
print(string.format("elapsed time: %.2f\n", os.clock() - x))
```

and now I'm getting some values that make sense!

Comment: Your use of os.difftime is fine (though you will get negative results since your arguments are "backwards" from what it expects). That being said your output just looks like your "do ... stuff" blocks just aren't taking any real time. Are they supposed to be taking some real amount of time? Does running test take a measurable amount of time?

Comment: @EtanReisner, yes, when I run my code, it does take some time for it to come back... I'm trying to narrow it down to a routine / line of code that is causing the bottleneck.  Also, please check out: http://lua-users.org/wiki/OsLibraryTutorial.  It doesn't look like I have a parms in reversed order.

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong about the ordering. I'd misread the t1/t2 argument order in the lua manual when I said that. Sorry. Do you see this delay between your printed output lines being printed or before/after they print?

Comment: @EtanReisner no worries Etan. I think I figured out how to us e the os.clock() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.clock` measures CPU time, not wall time. CPU time does not include time spent in `sleep`. So the script below still prints zero elapsed time:

```
local x = os.clock()
os.execute("sleep 60")
print(string.format("elapsed time: %.2f\n", os.clock() - x))
```

When you move `os.execute` into the loop, what you're probably measuring is the time to fork a shell. The script below print nonzero elapsed time, even if it is a short loop:

```
local x = os.clock()
for i=1,1000 do os.execute("true") end
print(string.format("elapsed time: %.2f\n", os.clock() - x))
```

Finally, you got zero elapsed time in the first loop because Lua is fast. Try changing the limit to 1000000:

```
local x = os.clock()
local s = 0
for i=1,1000000 do s = s + i end
print(string.format("elapsed time: %.2f\n", os.clock() - x))
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet does many rounds of addition and then executes one sleep call for one second.

```
for i=1,100000 do s = s + i end
os.execute("sleep "..1)
```

This snippet does the same amount of addition but sleeps for one second each time through the loop.

```
for i=1,100000 do 
   s = s + i 
   os.execute("sleep "..1)
end
```

That is a big difference.

Comment: Yeah Etan, that's pretty much the same as what I posted in my Edit 1. Thanks though

Comment: @dot I know. I was pointing out why your timings changed so wildly when you did that. The difference in time taken there is huge. I would have added this as a comment but the lack of formatting would have hurt comprehension tremendously.