# How to properly and efficiently shuffle a table's contents?

Tags: lua

I'm trying to shuffle a table's contents randomly. It works fine, except sometimes it doesn't return all the contents of the table. I printed out some of the keys of the table before shuffling, and they returned nil, but I'm not sure how to fix that. Here's the Lua:

```
local tab = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

function ReturnRandomTable(t)
   local newt = {}
   local i = 1
   repeat
      local rand = math.random(1,#t)
      newt[i] = t[rand]
      print(t[rand]) --sometimes prints nil
      t[rand] = nil
      i = i + 1
   until #t == 0
   return newt
end

table.shuffle = function(t)
   local newt = ReturnRandomTable(t)
   for i = #t,1,-1 do
      t[i] = nil
   end
   return newt
end

local randt = table.shuffle(tab)
for _,v in pairs(randt) do
   print(v)
end
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing `t[rand] = nil` to `table.remove(t,rand)`.

Comment: Add in code:
math.randomseed (os.time ())
then each time the script is run, the order of numbers will be different.

Comment: @SlawomirDziuba this is only true once per second!

Comment: @Piglet There was nothing about resolution in the question. You need some temporary entropy and time seems to be good. If you need a millisecond check, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463101/lua-current-time-in-milliseconds