# Lua 5.4.4 under msys2 : error loading module 'mylib' from file 'mylib'

Tags: gcc, lua, msys2

Starting from this example i build C mylib.so library in order to call C API function.

I use lua5.4.4 building it on my own 'make mingw under msys2' and install it under msys2 /mingw32/bin, /include, etx.

I started from this sample code
https://chsasank.com/lua-c-wrapping.html

Building it under msys2 with gcc -Wall-shared -fPIC -o mylib.so -I/mingw32/include mylib.c -llua

Then running ./libexample.lua with

```
#!/mingw32/bin/lua

package.cdpath = 'mylib'
local mylibtest = require 'mylib'
```

Getting output as this
error loading module 'mylib' from 'mylib'

Comment: `cdpath` or `cpath`?

Comment: Where your .so file is located?  Why do you need to modify `package.cpath`?

Comment: mylib.so is at root directory of lua test file.

Comment: Try to remove the line `package.cdpath = 'mylib'`

Comment: Already done. Same issue. I try too require './mylib.so'. Same issue. Is there possible incompatibility to try this sample under msys2 taking account that i make mingw lua 5.4.4  and getting lua.exe, install in /mingw32/bin ?

Comment: I tried this another sample highrestimer 'cause i need it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463101/lua-current-time-in-milliseconds.   compiled under msys2 mingw32 with gcc -Wall -shared -fPIC -o timer.so -I/mingw32/include HighResTimer.c -llua

Comment: What does `/path/to/lua.exe -e"print(package.cpath)"` print on your system?

Comment: It may happen `lua.exe` expects a module in `.dll`-file instead of `.so`

Comment: This is the result /mingw32/bin/lua.exe -e"print(package.cpath)"
C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\?.dll;C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\..\lib\lua\5.4\?.dll;C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\loadall.dll;.\?.dll

And a run of Highrestimer.lua

# ./HighResTimer.lua
C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\lua.exe: error loading module 'timer' from file '.\timer.dll':
        La proc�dure sp�cifi�e est introuvable.

stack traceback:
        [C]: in ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        ./HighResTimer.lua:9: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?

Comment: Save your `mylib.dll` to `C:\msys64\mingw32\lib\lua\5.4\mylib.dll`

Comment: Hum, that's what i obtain Mr Skriptunoff.  Thank you for help.     cp timer.dll /c/msys64/mingw32/lib/lua/5.4/

foo.bar@BAR-FOO MINGW32 /c/Users/foo.bar/source/Vim.8.2.5018/src/lua-5.4.4/src
# ./HighResTimer.lua
C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\lua.exe: error loading module 'timer' from file 'C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\..\lib\lua\5.4\timer.dll':
        La proc�dure sp�cifi�e est introuvable.

stack traceback:
        [C]: in ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        ./HighResTimer.lua:9: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?

Comment: You may have forgotten to change `luaopen_HighResolutionTimer` to `luaopen_timer`.  The name of C function (luaopen_*) should correspond to the name of dll and the name of module (in "require").

Comment: As a tribute to this forum :) , getting C stack overflow. uploaded files https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vHDudS7UQj1XzzjNvv9kGP5D2k9oRceJ/view?usp=drivesdk

The errors:
# gcc -Wall -shared -fPIC -o HighResTimer.dll -I/mingw32/include HighResTimer.c -llua
 MINGW32/c/Users/foo.bar/source/Vim.8.2.5018/src/lua-5.4.4/src
# ./HighResTimer.lua
C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\lua.exe: error loading module 'HighResTimer' from file '.\HighResTimer.lua':
        C stack overflow
stack traceback:
        [C]: in ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        .\HighResTimer.lua:9: in main chunk

Comment: This is because of names collision: you have the main file `HighResTimer.lua` and library `HighResTimer.dll`.  The names should be different.

Comment: Require works.  Thank you a lot

Comment: Uodate link if can help somebody https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vHDudS7UQj1XzzjNvv9kGP5D2k9oRceJ/view?usp=drivesdk. Thank a lot Mr Skriptunoff